# Connecting to mongodb behind AWS NLB sporadic timeouts

Tags: mongodb, aws-networking, network-load-balancer

For better or worse, this is how I have things set up now:

```
mongo client connects to:
  -> AWS Internal Network (TCP) Load balancer
    -> Traefik (reverse proxy)
      -> mongo (from docker image mongo:4.4.17)
```

(This setup was a quick hack to get mongodb in place.  I've done a lot of reading debugging this issue and learned maybe my setup isn't the best.  But I've found nothing to suggest it shouldn't work.)

**Issue:**

Connections will work until they don't.  My 'test' is a simple node script that opens a db connection and execute db.find(), then logs that.  It works a few times, then will hang.  The mongodb logs suggest the client reaches its timeout and disconnects.  Other than the client-side timeout, I see no errors to explain what mongo was doing for 30s.

If I make requests directly to Traefik or to mongo this issue goes away entirely.  So it must be related to the request going through the NLB.

**Some Logs:**

mongodb logs (level 0):
Test script (worked, got valid repsonse and exited cleanly):

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.848+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.20.21.43:57206","connectionId":13,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.853+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn13","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.20.21.43:57206","client":"conn13","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.862+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:42852","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.862+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:42852","client":"conn14","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.878+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"Authentication succeeded","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"user","authenticationDatabase":"tracker","remote":"10.20.31.176:42852","extraInfo":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.892+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn13","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.20.21.43:57206","connectionId":13,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:15.894+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn14","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:42852","connectionId":14,"connectionCount":2}}
```

Exact same test script, run a few seconds later that timed out after 30 seconds:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:37.143+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.20.21.43:49370","connectionId":15,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:37.147+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn15","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.20.21.43:49370","client":"conn15","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:43.980+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1667933203:980496][1:0x7fc8a881e700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 8, snapshot max: 8 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 195129"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:47.658+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:42300","connectionId":16,"connectionCount":4}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:46:47.658+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn16","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:42300","client":"conn16","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:47:07.163+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn15","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":2510}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:47:07.163+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn15","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.20.21.43:49370","connectionId":15,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:47:07.163+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn16","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:42300","connectionId":16,"connectionCount":2}}
```

Same test script - Log Level 3:
Unsuccessful (timeout at 30s)

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.522+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:57422","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.523+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22983,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Starting new executor thread in passthrough mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.526+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"ismaster":true,"client":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"},"compression":[],"helloOk":true,"$db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.526+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:57422","client":"conn2","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.526+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22934,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Starting server-side compression negotiation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.527+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22936,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"No compressors provided"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.527+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"ismaster":true,"client":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"},"compression":[],"helloOk":true,"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":329,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_query","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.527+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":317}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:29.527+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Ops known during interrupt","attr":{"ops":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:30.034+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:30.034+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23904,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Using maxAwaitTimeMS for awaitable isMaster protocol."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:36.026+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"WRITE",    "id":21976,   "ctx":"abortExpiredTransactions","msg":"Scanning sessions","attr":{"sessionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.037+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:57284","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.037+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":22983,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Starting new executor thread in passthrough mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"ismaster":true,"client":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"},"compression":[],"helloOk":true,"$db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:57284","client":"conn3","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22934,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Starting server-side compression negotiation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22936,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"No compressors provided"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"ismaster":true,"client":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.7.3"},"os":{"type":"Linux","name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.10.147-133.644.amzn2.x86_64"},"platform":"'Node.js v19.0.0, LE (unified)"},"compression":[],"helloOk":true,"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":329,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_query","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":452}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.038+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Ops known during interrupt","attr":{"ops":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.044+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22934,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Starting server-side compression negotiation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.044+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22935,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Compression negotiation not requested by client"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.044+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23905,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Using exhaust for isMaster or hello protocol"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.044+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":323,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.044+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":326}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.044+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Ops known during interrupt","attr":{"ops":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.045+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:40.045+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23904,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Using maxAwaitTimeMS for awaitable isMaster protocol."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.043+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"ismaster":1,"$db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.043+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22934,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Starting server-side compression negotiation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.043+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22935,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Compression negotiation not requested by client"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.043+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"ismaster":1,"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":304,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.043+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":579}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.043+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Ops known during interrupt","attr":{"ops":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22934,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Starting server-side compression negotiation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22935,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Compression negotiation not requested by client"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23905,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Using exhaust for isMaster or hello protocol"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":323,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22790,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":453}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Ops known during interrupt","attr":{"ops":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:50.055+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23904,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Using maxAwaitTimeMS for awaitable isMaster protocol."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:54.149+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23106,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-0","msg":"Reaping this thread","attr":{"nextThreadRetirementDate":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:57:24.149Z"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:54.149+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"EXECUTOR", "id":23105,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-0","msg":"Shutting down thread","attr":{"threadName":"AuthorizationManager-0","poolName":"AuthorizationManager"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:59.543+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":580}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:59.543+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"-",        "id":4892201, "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Internal assertion","attr":{"error":{"code":279,"codeName":"ClientDisconnect","errmsg":"operation was interrupted"},"location":"{fileName:\"src/mongo/util/interruptible.h\", line:398, functionName:\"operator()\"}"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:59.543+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22986,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Session from remote encountered a network error during SourceMessage","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:57284","error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Connection closed by peer"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:59.543+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"10.20.31.176:57284","connectionId":3,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:59.543+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21962,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Assertion while executing command","attr":{"command":"hello","db":"admin","commandArgs":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"},"error":"ClientDisconnect: operation was interrupted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-08T18:56:59.543+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","command":{"hello":true,"helloOk":true,"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"636aa6433c5de5c55d30c876"},"counter":0},"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"ok":0,"errMsg":"operation was interrupted","errName":"ClientDisconnect","errCode":279,"reslen":117,"locks":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
```

**Test Script:**

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

let url;
//url = 'mongodb://user:pass@10.20.11.28:3204/tracker';
//url = 'mongodb://user:pass@10.20.21.43:3204/tracker';
//url = 'mongodb://user:pass@10.20.31.176:3204/tracker';
url = 'mongodb:/user:pass@ninja-internal-network-1234567.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:3204/tracker';

console.log(url);
dbclient = new mongodb.MongoClient(url, {auto_reconnect:true, ssl: false, poolSize: 16, keepAlive: true, retryWrites:false, useUnifiedTopology: true})
console.log(dbclient);

dbclient.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("connection error:", err);
  }
  db = dbclient.db('tracker')
  db.collection('visitors', function(a,b){
    b.find({aid:7}).toArray(function(err, items) {
      console.log(items.length);
      console.log(items[0]);
      dbclient.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: For the curious port `3204` is pretty arbitrary and it does map through to mongodb's 27017.

Comment: having the same issue, did you mange to get it working?

Comment: you know - I didn't. I just hardcoded our one ip/port (super small deployment right now) and today it bit me in the ass.  guess it should get figured out

Comment: interesting that you also facing this issue.. i kind of having similar setup.. how is it going now?

Comment: @karthikeayan see my answer

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. We have a MongoDB exposed via an AWS NLB deployed within our Kubernetes Cluster. We could test connections were timing out by running `curl nlb_address:27017 -v` from a dummy pod inside of our cluster.

Upon further investigating we came across

> Connections time out for requests from a target to its load balancer
> Check whether client IP preservation is enabled on your target group.
> NAT loopback, also known as hairpinning, is not supported when client
> IP preservation is enabled. If an instance is a client of a load
> balancer that it's registered with, and it has client IP preservation
> enabled, the connection succeeds only if the request is routed to a
> different instance. If the request is routed to the same instance it
> was sent from, the connection times out because the source and
> destination IP addresses are the same.
>
> If an instance must send requests to a load balancer that it's
> registered with, do one of the following:
>
> Disable client IP preservation.
>
> Ensure that containers that must communicate, are on different
> container instances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#loopback-timeout

This made sense for us as the connections which were being dropped came from within our kubernetes cluster, our mongodb was also deployed within our kubernetes cluster.

---

**Solution**: `Disable Client IP preservation.` on the LB Target Group.

Which can either be done via the AWS Load Balancer Controller with the following annotation: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/guide/service/annotations/

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: preserve_client_ip.enabled=true`

OR via the AWS Dashboard: Toggle Off `Preserve Client IP Addresses`

[image]

After toggling off and rerunning a few curl tests, we noticed that we were no longer being timedout.

**notes:**

- We were also first advised to enable `Cross Zone Load Balancing` on the LB which did not work for us.

**references:**

https://build.thebeat.co/a-curious-case-of-aws-nlb-timeouts-in-kubernetes-522bd88a3399

https://repost.aws/questions/QUbwjtwhGOTZ-h2eTy3MCjsw/aws-eks-internal-network-load-balancer-nlb-timed-out-while-trying-to-connect-from-underlying-eks-worker-node